# Unable to pass value of props in React component

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to iterate over a list of json values and create cards based on that. I tried many approaches but feel I am missing something while accessing props in my components.

Below is my JSON

```
let mockdata = {values : [{name : 'John'}, {name: 'Mike'}, {name : 'Sam'}]};
```

This is how my app.js looks like. I am importing cardcontainer in the app.

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    items: []
    }
  componentDidMount() {
      fetch(endpoint)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(({values : items}) => this.setState({items}))
  }
  render() {
      return (
            <div className="App">
              <header className="App-header">
                <h1 className="App-title">Ping Pong Time Table</h1>
              </header>
              <div className="card-container">
              <CardContainer/>
            </div>
          </div>
          );
  }
}

export default App;
```

This how my cardcontainer looks like

```
class CardBody extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="card-body">
        <p className="date">March 20 2015</p>

        <h2>{this.props.title}</h2>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class Card extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <article className="card">
        <CardBody title={this.props.value}/>
      </article>
    )
  }
}

class CardContainer extends React.Component {

  render(){
    var info = this.props.items;
    console.log(info);
    var elements = [];
    for(let val in info){
          elements.push(<Card value={ info[name] } />);
        }
        return (
            <div>
            {elements}
            </div>
        );
  }
}

export default CardContainer;
```

I have tried different approaches about this but somehow console.log(info) in cardcontainer gives undefined. Any help or pointers is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing any properties to your CardContainer. To pass properties to a React component, you pass them like this:

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    items: []
    }
  componentDidMount() {
      fetch(endpoint)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(({values : items}) => this.setState({items}))
  }
  render() {
      return (
            <div className="App">
              <header className="App-header">
                <h1 className="App-title">Ping Pong Time Table</h1>
              </header>
              <div className="card-container">
              <CardContainer items={this.state.items} />
            </div>
          </div>
          );
  }
}

export default App;
```

You can pass as many properties as you like. These properties are available to the components on its `this.props`.

Answer (score 0):

You have pass `this.state.items` as props to `CardContainer` and in `CardContainer` pass `item.name` to `Card` component

```
class App extends React.Component {
   constructor() {
       super();
       this.state = {
          items: [{name : 'John'}, {name: 'Mike'}, {name : 'Sam'}]
       }
   }
   render(){
   return (
     <div className="App">
          <header className="App-header">
            <h1 className="App-title">Ping Pong Time Table</h1>
          </header>
          <div className="card-container">
          <CardContainer items = {this.state.items} />
        </div>
      </div>
  );
 }
}
```

CardContainer

```
class CardContainer extends React.Component {

   render(){
       var info = this.props.items;
       console.log(info);
       var elements = info.map((item) => (<Card value={item.name} />));
       return (
            <div>
                {elements}
            </div>
       );
   }
 }
```

The working code is available in https://codesandbox.io/s/woz4v2nxmw